# Which method is preferred to transfer the data between front-end and back-end in React SPA model

Tags: json, reactjs, forms, jsp, single-page-application

I am building a webapp using react and Spring and it's a SPA model. Which method is preferred to transfer the data between front-end and back-end, JSON or jsp content form method?

Comment: If you are asking about preferred lifecycle method for API call then componenetDidMount will do the job.

Comment: No. I am asking about format of the transferring data. Can I use json format or jsp content form. Which one is preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely up to you how you format your data. This has nothing to do with React or a SPA.